# Unity Firebase Access without Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I understand that the typical authentication system uses Google or one of their providers, but I have my own authentication system that isn't compatible.

I was wondering if it was possible to create a "service account" that is baked into the app as it's distributed. My logic is that this "service account" is secure because we will require my authentication system's approval to utilize.

I am aware of an AnonymousAuthentication option, but I want to avoid presenting an external (read: Google) login screen as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase provides a relatively easy way to use your own custom authentication to sign in.

The most straightforward approach to using your [custom auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/custom-auth) is to pass login credentials to your server, confirm them using your own method and [return tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for users to authenticate  with.